# RabbitMQ Redirect message to another exchange if current message doesn't have any binded queue

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Is there a way to configure some policy to redirect messages from one exchange to another exchange, if the current exchange doesn't have any binded queue?

I got a situation where RabbitMQ after restart loose some bindings and my messages were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the feature is called [Alternate Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html), and it works like this:

- You set a "policy" which matches exchange A, with a key of 'alternate-exchange' and a value naming exchange B. Alternatively, you can set it as a property directly when creating the exchange.
- Any message routed to exchange A which doesn't match any binding will be routed to exchange B.
- Exchange B processes it in the normal way, and can even have an Alternate Exchange of its own.